# Why does selecting YYYY-MM-DD from a pandas datetime index not behave as expected?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe, a MWE is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import get_data_yahoo
aapl = get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
```

I can then select a year from the datetime index as follows:

```
In [28]: aapl['2010']
Out[28]:
                  Open        High         Low       Close     Volume  \
Date
2010-01-04  213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998  123432400
2010-01-05  214.599998  215.589994  213.249994  214.379993  150476200
2010-01-06  214.379993  215.230000  210.750004  210.969995  138040000
2010-01-07  211.750000  212.000006  209.050005  210.580000  119282800
...
```

I can also select a month from the dataframe easily too, like this:

```
In [29]: aapl['2010-10']
Out[29]:
                  Open        High         Low       Close     Volume  \
Date
2010-10-01  286.149994  286.579990  281.349991  282.520004  112035700
2010-10-04  281.600010  282.900013  277.769989  278.639996  108825500
2010-10-05  281.999992  289.449989  281.819988  288.939991  125491800
2010-10-06  289.589993  291.989994  285.259987  289.190010  167717200
2010-10-07  290.339996  290.480000  286.910011  289.219997  102099900
...
```

Why then can I not go a step further and select by day too?

```
In [30]: aapl['2010-10-01']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-260f9bf24ef2> in <module>()
----> 1 aapl['2010-10-01']
...
...
KeyError: '2010-10-01'
```

Instead I have to do this...

```
In [31]: aapl[aapl.index=='2010-10-01']
Out[31]:
                  Open       High         Low       Close     Volume  \
Date
2010-10-01  286.149994  286.57999  281.349991  282.520004  112035700
```

Is this intended behaviour? And if so why?

Comment: I'm surprised that this works like this but you can use `.loc` also: `In [331]:

aapl.loc['2010-10-01']
Out[331]:
Open         2.861500e+02
High         2.865800e+02
Low          2.813500e+02
Close        2.825200e+02
Volume       1.120357e+08
Adj Close    3.757978e+01
Name: 2010-10-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64`